# access a constexpr member variable of a derived class through a base class reference via CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, crtp

I'm running into an error when trying to access a `constexpr` member variable of a derived class through a base class reference via CRTP;

```
template <typename Der>
struct Base
{
    constexpr std::size_t getsize()
    {
        constexpr const auto &b = static_cast<Der*>(this)->arr;
        return b.size();
        //return static_cast<Der*>(this)->arr.size(); // this works
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    static constexpr std::array<int, 10> arr = {};
};

int main(){
    Derived d;    
    return d.getsize();
}
```

Error:

```
<source>:11:31: error: constexpr variable 'b' must be initialized by a constant expression
        constexpr const auto &b = static_cast<Der*>(this)->arr;
                              ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:24:14: note: in instantiation of member function 'Base<Derived>::getsize' requested here
    return d.getsize();
             ^
<source>:11:53: note: use of 'this' pointer is only allowed within the evaluation of a call to a 'constexpr' member function
        constexpr const auto &b = static_cast<Der*>(this)->arr;
                                                    ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

**Update**
It turns out that removing the constexpr in the reference works. I'd like to understand why this works ?

```
        auto &b = static_cast<Der*>(this)->arr;
        return b.size();
```

Comment: You might use `Der::arr`.

Comment: It comes down to what is considered a compile-time constant and what is not. In the context of `Base`, the compiler has no way of knowing if `static_cast<Der*>(this)->arr;` is indeed a constant expression, since it depends on the derived class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informally, you should imagine there being a rule that a `constexpr` *variable* defined inside a function is required to be initialized by an expression that is *always* a constant expression regardless of the circumstances under which the function is called. In particular, you can always do something like this:

```
Base<Derived> b;
b.getSize();
```

in which case `static_cast<Der*>(this)->arr` is not a constant expression, since it is in fact UB. Because of the *possibility* of things like this, your function can't compile at all even though you may never call it in this manner anyway.

The *actual* rule you are violating is [expr.const]/5.1. A constant expression *E* may not evaluate `this`, unless it's by (directly or indirectly) calling some member function inside of which the evaluation of `this` occurs. In particular, this means that if we have some code like this:

```
// namespace scope
struct S {
    constexpr const S* get_self() {
        const S* result = this;
        return result;
    }
};
constexpr S s;
constexpr const S* sp = s.get_self();
```

Here, `s.get_self()` is a constant expression, because the access to `this` only occurs inside the `get_self()` function, which is part of the evaluation of `s.get_self()`. But we cannot make `result` `constexpr`, because if it were so, we no longer get to "count" the enclosing function; the initialization step would have to qualify in and of itself as a constant expression, which it is not, since the access to `this` is now "bare".

For your code this implies that `getsize()` actually may return a constant expression (for those calls that do not trigger UB as described above) but `b` cannot be made `constexpr`.